# div flips only one time in infinite loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a div item in table, i am rotating the div in JS and i am calling the function repeatedly, but the flip happens only for first time when the function is executed and again when function is called it just shows the div, without flipping the div.

The thing what i need is, when each time i call the function the div should flip the div.

How can i do that?

Css:

```
.box-1{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
function startSlidecat1(started) {
  for (var i = 0; i < footwear.length; i++) {
    var image = footwear[i][0];
    imgslidercat1(image, i * 2100, i == footwear.length - 1);
  }
};

function imgslidercat1(image, timeout, last) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('flip-1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('category-1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('category-1').innerHTML = "";
    var product = document.getElementById('category-1');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    product.appendChild(elem);
    elem.src = image;
    if (last) {
      flip();
    }
  }, timeout);
}
startSlidecat1();

function flip(){
    $('#category-1').delay(100).css('display', 'none');
    $('.box-1').delay(100).css('display', 'block');
    $('.box-1').transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateY: '360deg'
      },200)  
    setTimeout(startSlidecat1, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: `if (last){flip();}` is this really required?

Comment: @Arvind yes.... to call function if the flag is set to last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time when div is flipping, its `rotateY` value changes from `180deg` to `360deg`, that is visible. But from second time onward, its value remains at `360deg` so nothing happens. You just need to reset the value each time you call the function like this,

```
$('.box-1').css({transform:'perspective(100px) rotateY(180deg)'});
```

You can include this inside the `startSlidecat1` function like this,

```
function startSlidecat1(started) {
  $('.box-1').css({transform:'perspective(100px) rotateY(180deg)'});
  for (var i = 0; i < footwear.length; i++) {
    var image = footwear[i][0];
    imgslidercat1(image, i * 2100, i == footwear.length - 1);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm gonna turn 360 degrees and walk away from this problem